# My PHP-defined strings are being scrambled. Why?

Tags: php, string

I have this piece of code.

```
$archivePath = 'archive/archive.txt';
$archiveReader = fopen($archivePath, 'r');
$numberOfStatements = 0;
while (!feof($archiveReader)) {
    $thisLine = fgets($archiveReader);
    list($identifier, $state, $day, $month, $year, $tags) = explode('|', $thisLine);
    $tags = explode(',', $tags);
    $lineToEcho = "statement #" . $identifier . " is " . $state . ". Date:" . $day . "." . $month . "." . $year . " tags: ";
    $numberOfTags = count($tags);

    for ($k = 0; $k < $numberOfTags; $k++) {
        if ($k != 0) {
            $lineToEcho .= $tags[$k] . ", ";
        } 
        $lineToEcho .= $tags[$k];
    }
    $lineToEcho .= "<br>";
    echo $lineToEcho;
    $numberOfStatements++;
}
fclose($archiveReader);
```

The code is supposed to return strings in this format

```
statement #0 is raw. Date:30.01.14 tags: war,piece
```

But returns in this format instead:

```
statement #0 is raw. Date:30 01 14.war,piece . tags:
```

Why is my string reformatted and how do I stop it from happening?

EDIT: archive.txt looks like this:

```
0|raw|30 01 14|war,piece
1|raw|30 01 14|drugs,abstinence
```

EDIT2: when viewing source in FireFox, I see this:

```
statement #0 is raw. Date:30 01 14.war,piece
. tags: <br>statement #1 is raw. Date:30 01 14.drugs,abstinence
. tags: <br>//next entry
```

Answer (score 2):

This line looks bad:

```
$lineToEcho = $tags[$k] . ", ";
```

It should probably be:

```
$lineToEcho .= $tags[$k] . ", ";
//          ^-- . here
```

---

```
$a .= "b"; // is equivalent to
$a = $a . "b";
```

Comment: I updated my code according to your suggestion but I get the same result. Question is revised with new code.

Comment: Ok, another guess is that the value of `$year` is `14.war,piece ` and not `14`. Can you confirm this? Can you show us what the file looks like?

Comment: Edit your question ;) you have more space there.

Comment: Frits: Yes, you make sense. I deleted the comment and posted in the Question in stead.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of adding values to lineToEcho works fine. Problem is, it will be overwritten in your for loop:

```
$lineToEcho = "statement #" . $identifier . " is " . $state . ". Date:" . $day . "." . $month . "." . $year . " tags: ";
```

In your for loop, you arent using those dots as you want, you are just addind your tags separated by comma.

```
for ($k = 0; $k < $numberOfTags; $k++) {
    if ($k != 0) {
        $lineToEcho = $tags[$k] . ", ";
    } 
    $lineToEcho = $lineToEcho . $tags[$k];
}
```

So if you want to keep both lines, the one from above and the one from your loop, remove the if clause that resets $lineToEcho.